# Elastic Search: Exact phrase to have higher score + keep analysis

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a simple `multi_match` query on a specific `type` of an index.

As per the below screenshot, when the search query is **Hyderabad, In** or even **Hyderabad, Ind**, the intended result appears with a lower score. In this case, the intended result is **Hyderabad, India (INHYD)**

[image: Unintended suggestion]

**EDIT**: Below is my updated query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "_all": {
              "query": "Hyderabad, In",
              "fuzziness": 4,
              "prefix_length": 2,
              "operator": "and"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the full ElasticSearch trace:

```
Elasticsearch TRACE: 2016-08-17T07:33:21Z
  -> POST http://192.168.99.100:9200/shipwaves/ports/_search?size=10&from=0&default_operator=AND
  {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "_all": {
                "query": "Hyderabad, In",
                "fuzziness": 4,
                "prefix_length": 2,
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  <- 200
  {
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
    }
  }
```

**How can I tweak the query to give me the intended result a higher score?**

Note: I have learnt that using `not_analyzed` index will make this work, but I do want analysis to be done so phrases like **Hydrabad" (a letter missing) are matched. So I am keeping the analysis to simple.

**Elastic Search v2.3.5**

Comment: why would `In` match on `India` with fuzziness:1 .? The edit distance is more than 1. You probably should set muti-match operator to `and` also look into [edgegram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html)

Comment: Thanks! I have modified my query to include `"fuzziness": 4`, `"prefix_length": 2` and `"operator": "and"`, so with the prefix_length, the "In" would match, and the edit distance is 3, I believe (**dia**). It doesn't match it still, unless I search for **Hyderabad, Ind". Any more ideas that would help this case without using something like edgegram?